# Объект IAsyncResult не был возвращен соответствующим асинхронным методом данного класса?

Tags: c#

Создаю socks 5. В процессе обработки ссылки появляется ошибка.

```
class StateObject
{
    public Socket workSocket = null;            //сокет клиента
    public const int bufferSize = 64;         //max размер буфера
    public byte[] buffer = new byte[bufferSize];//буфер
    public string sb = null;//принятные данные в виде строки
}

class server
{
    StateObject stateGL = new StateObject();
    private Socket socket_client;
    private IPEndPoint ip;

    public server()
    {
        try
        {
            IPAddress localAddress = IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1");
            Socket listenSocket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
            IPEndPoint ipEndpoint = new IPEndPoint(localAddress, 2200);

            listenSocket.Bind(ipEndpoint);

            listenSocket.Listen(1);
            listenSocket.BeginAccept(new AsyncCallback(ReceiveCallback), listenSocket);listenSocket.LocalEndPoint);

            while (true)
            {
            }

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Произошла ошибка: {0}", e.ToString());
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }

    public void ReceiveCallback(IAsyncResult AsyncCall)
    {
        System.Text.UTF8Encoding encoding = new System.Text.UTF8Encoding();
        byte[] messageRecv = new byte[64];
        string Recv = null;
        Socket listener = (Socket)AsyncCall.AsyncState;
        Socket client = listener.EndAccept(AsyncCall);  //браузер
        while (true)
        {
            int length = client.Receive(messageRecv);
            Recv = Recv + Encoding.UTF8.GetString(messageRecv, 0,length);
            if (length < 64)
            {
                stateGL.sb = Recv;
                break;
            }
        }
        //начало запросов
        clientConnectServer("127.0.0.10", 2200);
        Console.WriteLine("Закрытие соединения");
        client.Close();

        listener.BeginAccept(new AsyncCallback(ReceiveCallback), listener);
    }

    //создание сокета клиента
    public void clientConnectServer(string ip, int port)
    {
        this.ip = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse(ip), port);
        this.socket_client = new Socket(this.ip.AddressFamily, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
        Connect();
    }

    //подключение к серверу
    public void Connect()
    {
        try
        {
            this.socket_client.BeginConnect(this.ip, new AsyncCallback(ConnectCallBack), this.socket_client);
        }
        catch (Exception x) { Console.WriteLine("Error connect server1"); Console.ReadKey(); }
    }

    //метод для завершения операции
    private void ConnectCallBack(IAsyncResult ar)
    {
        Socket handle = (Socket)ar.AsyncState;
        try
        {
            byte[] message = { 5, 1, 2 };
            //привествие
            Send(message, message.Length);
            this.socket_client.EndConnect(ar);
        }
        catch (Exception e) { Console.WriteLine("2" + e.Message); Console.ReadKey(); this.socket_client.EndConnect(ar); }
    }
    //отправка сообщения
    public void Send(byte[] message, int length)
    {
        try
        {
            this.socket_client.BeginSend(message, 0, length, SocketFlags.None, new AsyncCallback(SendCallBack), this.socket_client);
        }
        catch (Exception x) { Console.WriteLine("Error connect server2"); Console.ReadKey(); }
    }

    private void SendCallBack(IAsyncResult ar)
    {
        try
        {
            Socket handle = ar.AsyncState as Socket;
            handle.EndSend(ar);
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("SendCallBack");
        }
            Receive();
    }

    public void Receive()
    {
        StateObject state = new StateObject();
        try
        {
            state.workSocket = this.socket_client;
            state.workSocket.BeginReceive(state.buffer, 0, StateObject.bufferSize, SocketFlags.None, new AsyncCallback(ReceiveCallBack), state);
        }catch(Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("1" + e.Message);
            Console.ReadKey();
            state.workSocket.EndReceive(null);
        }
    }

    private void ReceiveCallBack(IAsyncResult ar)
    {
        try
        {
            StateObject state = ar.AsyncState as StateObject;
            Socket handl = state.workSocket;
            if (handl.Connected)
            {
                int bytes = handl.EndReceive(ar);
                if (bytes > 0)
                {
                    if (state.buffer[0] == 5 && state.buffer[1] == 2)
                        Console.WriteLine("Верное привествие");
                    ip4_6_nameHost();
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception) { Console.WriteLine("Error receive"); Console.ReadKey(); }
    }

    private void ip4_6_nameHost()
    {
        byte[] privestrieNext = new byte[64];
        try
        {
            Send(privestrieNext, 5 + name.Length + Port.Length);
        }
        catch (Exception x) 
        { 
            Console.WriteLine("IPIPIP");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

}

Исключение выбрасывается на этой строчке:

```
catch (Exception e) { Console.WriteLine("2" + e.Message); Console.ReadKey(); this.socket_client.EndConnect(ar); }
```

> ```
> Объект IAsyncResult не был возвращен соответствующим асинхронным
> ```
>
> методом данного класса

В чём может быть дело?

Comment: Эээ... Слишком много кода. Попробуйте укоротить программу до _абсолютно необходимого_ минимума, который воспроизводит проблему.

Например, функции `proverka` и `portName` наверняка не важны.

Comment: сократил. Оставил самое главное

Comment: @Vla00: Хм. А что делает `while (true) { }`? Вы же вешаете поток.

Comment: если я уберу этот цикл. То программа сразу при запуске закроется

Comment: @Vla00, у вас цикл бесконечный в конструкторе. Вы даже объект класса создать не сможете.

Comment: @Vla00: Ну, вы должны в цикле принимать соединения, у вас же сервер!

Comment: если я сделаю как вы говорите. То когда сервер примет одно сообщение он его зациклит и в дальнейшем не принимает сообщения... Я уже всё пробовал, так как я сделал всё работает. Вот только ошибка вылетает вышесказанная. Может вы мне насчёт этого что-нибудь подскажете?

Answer (score 3):

Смотрите.

У вас `EndConnect` должен вызываться на то же `socket_client`, что и `BeginConnect`. А у вас за это время `socket_client` может поменяться, если вызовется ещё раз `clientConnectServer`. (Об этом собственно говорит сообщение об ошибке.)

Так что вам нужно в `ConnectCallBack` использовать `handle` вместо `this.socket_client`.

Тем не менее, всё равно не пойдёт: у вас бесконечный цикл в конструкторе, программа не будет правильно работать. Попробуйте перейти с устаревших, но довольно сложных конструкций с `BeginXX`/`EndXX`/`IAsyncResult` на современный `async`/`await`-интерфейс. Вот вам [пример](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12631467/276994).